# Perl Creating a CSV file

Tags: perl, csv

I am trying to create a CSV file which reads in a CSV file and then outputs the data in the format:

```
Type: ABC
    A: Hello 
    B: World
    C: Test-Data, Testing
Type: ABC
    A: Hello 
    B: World
    C: Test-Data, Testing
```

With the input data looking like this

```
0: "ABC", "Hello", "World", "Test-Data, Testing"
1: "ABC", "Hello", "World", "Test-Data, Testing"
```

I started off by reading the [Text:CSV](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emakamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm#bind_columns) and then created

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $file = 'file.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/});

open my $input, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline ($input){    
    next if ($. == 1);
    if ($csv->parse($_)) 
    {   
        print "variable: $_";
        my @columns = $csv->fields();
        print "Type: $columns[0]\n\t A: $columns[1]\n\t B:$columns[2] \n\t C:$columns[3]";
    }
    else
    {       
        my $error = $csv->error_diag;
        print "Failed to parse line: $error";
    }   
}
```

Though it doesn't seem to be working, I thought it would read in the file.csv to $file and then loop around the the while loop using the *getline* to read in each line of the file.

What am i missing here? I was wondering if anyone would be able to help; I have tried to include as much information as possible.

Comment: is your input data above correct? or did you make a mistake copying and pasting? it does not seem to make sense to me. Where did "Cheers" come from?

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is trying to parse a line which is already parsed:

```
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($input){    # your row is now in $row
....
if ($csv->parse($_))  # Wrong! This is already done with getline()
```

Simply remove your erroneous code in the `if/else` clause and use

```
my @columns = @$row;
```

And your print statement should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, when I removed the code it still doesn't print anything out.

Comment: Then you need to figure out why. Insert debug print statements.